# How is this working pl/sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Please explain how is this working, Thx.

```
DECLARE   
CURSOR ab IS
SELECT emp.ename, emp.sal, dept.loc
FROM emp
JOIN dept ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno;
TYPE tbl_join IS TABLE OF cc%ROWTYPE;
l_table tbl_join;
BEGIN
OPEN cc;
FETCH cc BULK COLLECT INTO l_table;
CLOSE cc;
FOR indx IN
1 .. l_table.COUNT
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_table(indx).ename);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_table(indx).sal);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_table(indx).loc);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: It isn't working. It defines a cursor named `ab` and then refers to a cursor named `cc` that doesn't exist. Probably line 2 should be `cursor cc is`. By the way code in general is more readable when laid out neatly with indentation, and in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

- Fetch employee name, salary and location details into the CURSOR ab.
- For every row in the cursor print the details in a loop.
- The loop is terminated when it reaches the total count of rows.

For cursors, refer [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pl_sql_cursors.htm)

> A PL/SQL cursor is used to retrieve and process zero or more rows of
>   data.  There are a number of steps to use a cursor and depending on
>   how you implement the cursor, you can control each step or have the
>   database perform them.  A PL/SQL cursor is based on a SELECT
>   statement, normally declared in the declaration section of a PL/SQL
>   block.  The statement is not restricted as to the columns retrieved or
>   number of tables joined.

This snippet is using bulk collect, see [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_bulk_collect.htm).

> One method of fetching data is an Oracle bulk collect. With Oracle
>   bulk collect, the PL/SQL engine tells the SQL engine to collect many
>   rows at once and place them in a collection.  During an Oracle bulk
>   collect, the SQL engine retrieves all the rows and loads them into the
>   collection and switches back to the PL/SQL engine.  When rows are
>   retrieved using Oracle bulk collect, they are retrieved with only two
>   context switches.  The larger the number of rows you would like to
>   collect with Oracle bulk collect, the more performance improvement you
>   will see using an Oracle bulk collect.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. Please see the explanation below:

**Declaration potion:**

- 'ab' is declared as cursor which retrieves ename, sal & loc data when it is called. It's based on query mentioned as join query.
- 'tbl_join' is a custom datatype which is declared as table.
- 'l_table' is variable declared as tbl_join custom datatype created earlier.

**Execution portion**

- Open cc means open cursor
- Fetch cc retrieves data based on cursor query and insert it into l_table
- close cc is closing cursor.
- For each loop is used to iterate records of l_table. Count is used for retrieving total row of that l_table. So, loop will iterate l_table.count times.
- Dbms_output.put_line is to print values of the parameter passed in it. Here table record number is passed with which column value to print.
- Loop ..... End Loop is the syntax for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cursor should be named 'cc' instead of 'ab'.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR ab -- This is a corsor. A prepared statement which you can call during executing
    IS
        SELECT emp.ename, emp.sal, dept.loc
          FROM emp JOIN dept ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno;

    TYPE tbl_join IS TABLE OF cc%ROWTYPE; -- this is a table-type. Like an array of antoher type. In this example it is an array of the result of cc. 

    l_table   tbl_join; -- this is a variable of the table-type, which you can fill with data
BEGIN
    OPEN cc; -- here you open the cursor cc. I guess your cursor 'ab' (1st row) should be named 'cc' and opened here.

    FETCH cc BULK COLLECT INTO l_table; -- you read all you data from the cursor and stick it into you variable 'l_table'.

    CLOSE cc; -- you're done with you cursor, because of this you close it.

    FOR indx IN 1 .. l_table.COUNT -- a for-loop to loop through you table-variable.
    LOOP
        -- you access the elements of your table with the loop-variable 'indx'.
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_table (indx).ename); -- you access the fiels of your element.
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_table (indx).sal);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_table (indx).loc);
    END LOOP;
END;
```